# Does saliva on lips break fast?

Tags: sawm

As-salamu alaykum. I understand that we can swallow our saliva in the mouth, but while talking and moving our mouth it gets wet with our saliva as well. I'm talking about outer lips. I'm really concerned that this breaks my fast if I somehow accidentally swallow it or something. Also, what about licking our lips? Does it break my fast?

Answer (score 1):

No. Salvia doesn’t break the fast whatsoever.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I found this: "If the fasting person deliberately swallows his saliva after it had come out to his lips, he breaks his fast according to the Shaafa‘is and Hanbalis, because in that case the saliva has become detached from its place, which is the inside of the mouth, so swallowing it is like swallowing anything else that is separate from the mouth."

Comment: @amzaaa please share your findings in posts not via comments as comments are intended for clarification and are cleared by the community bot, mods etc. And if you want a detailed view you should address that in your question. Instead of discussing answers based on an input you didn't share.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you could provide evidences supporting your claim and elaborate more. See [answer].

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/275556/if-he-swallows-saliva-after-it-came-out-to-the-lips-does-that-break-the-fast-and-is-there-scholarly-consensus-on-the-issue

Comment: There you go that's the source